# Linux, CentOS 6.2: Unable to fetch data from SSL sites (cURL, wget, etc)

Tags: linux, ssl, curl

Machine: CentOS 6.2

I've had a Perl script which I've been using for ages, which has previously had no problem (and still doesn't) fetching data using LWP from port 80 locations. However, attempting to fetch from https locations, on port 443, always fails.

To simplify the diagnostics, I figured I'd try the same idea from the command line using cURL and wget, but these also fail with https, while they also both work fetching regular http data.

Figuring that the same problem affects all three methods, I'm trying to ascertain exactly what it is that might be wrong, and how to fix it. It's a dedicated server, and I have root access so I can pretty much do what I want to.

I've tried forcing cURL to use ipv4, and a bunch of other flags that looked interesting, but I always end up with the requests failing with "curl: (7) couldn't connect to host".

```
$ cat debugdump.txt
== Info: About to connect() to www.xyz.com port 443 (#0)
== Info: Trying 194.xxx.xxx.xx... == Info: Connection timed out
== Info: couldn't connect to host
== Info: Closing connection #0
```

... and similar connection time-outs with wget as well.

If I try fetching the same data with http, and with the -L flag (to follow redirects) then it will similarly fail on the secure portion of it.

So, basically I want to be able to retrieve remote data served via https, but am currently unable to do so. I know I definitely should be able to. I've spent ages trying to resolve this, but so far to no avail. Any useful information to help solve the problem would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**
Additional info: I'm not really too familiar with firewalls, but FYI, the entries in  /etc/sysconfig/iptables relating to port 443 are:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -j Cid2676X....  
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -j Cid2676X...
```

However, I'm not sure why/if I'd need to open port 443 (if it's not already open) anyway; I mean, I'm fetching from port 443 on another server, not listening for traffic on my 443; surely I'm using some other random port on my own machine to fetch with?

**Edit 2**
Figured out that if I temporarily disable the iptables then the problem goes away. Of course, I need to have the iptables active, so I need to know what it is about the iptables that is preventing me fetching from secure sites. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Are you sure the https is on port 443? It might be on 8080? Maybe the certificate on the server is self-signed or some how invalid so you might have to ignore certificate warning some how (i.e. wget --no-check-certificate ...).

Comment: Definitely port 443, but it resolves that bit itself anyway. I've tried the same thing with multiple hosts with the same results. The certificates are valid. I don't think the port is the problem, but rather something else about using the https protocol.

Comment: Can you connect with netcat to port 443 on any of those hosts from your server? Is port 443 open in the firewall? Does the server have a local firewall?

Comment: Elliot; no, cannot connect with netcat; I get the same sort of thing: "nc: connect to 194.xxx.xxx.xx port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out". The server does have a local firewall, as evidenced by the output from "iptables status", but I'm not really knowledgeable enough to interpret any of it. The destinations I'm trying to connect to can basically be any server which is serving data via https (i.e. they all fail). Thanks.

Comment: I'd say that your web server is not listening on port 443 otherwise, if what you have told us is accurate, you'd be able to connect.  On your web server execute `lsof -i:443`

Comment: ... that's `sudo lsof -i:443`

Comment: No output from that command.